# RobotFramework: How to get URL of link on page

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Does RobotFramework have any way of finding a link's URL to then paste into same browser and goto it in same window. The link exists in a button/link on the first page.

Reason i ask is because it opens a new window (which i dont want it to do)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Get element attribute](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) to get the value of the href attribute.

Here is an example using an xpath to find the element:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

Suite Setup     open browser    about:blank    chrome
Suite Teardown  close all browsers

*** Test cases ***
Example
    go to   http://www.example.com
    ${url}=  get element attribute   xpath=//a[text()='More information...']  href
    Should be equal  ${url}  http://www.iana.org/domains/example
```

Comment: This answer was once correct, but as of today (2021) it would throw an error, saying "Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute' expected 2 arguments, got 1". 
But it's easy to fix, just replace the "@" by two empty spaces: 
 ${url}=  get element attribute   xpath=//a[text()='More information...']  href

Comment: @ElAckabar: thanks for letting me know. I've updated the example.